# Proof of recurrence between cumulants and central-moments

Tags: moments, cumulants

According to Wikipedia, the $n$th cumulant $\kappa_n$ is related to the central-moments $\theta_n$ by the following recurrence:

$$\kappa_n = \theta_n - \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{m-1} \kappa_m \theta_{n-m}$$

which allows one to compute the cumulants sequentially, given the central-moments. The Wikipedia page offers no reference or proof of this formula. What's the proof of this formula?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation given by Wikipedia connects cumulants to moments (generally).

A proof of a formula connecting cumulants to *central moments* is found in [A Recursive Formulation of the Old Problem of Obtaining Moments from Cumulants and Vice Versa](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.1995.10476146)

Letting $K(t)$ be the cumulant-generating function, and $M(t)$ the moment-generating function. The relationship between the two is
\begin{equation}
M(t)=\exp{\left[K(t)\right]}
\end{equation}
The proof follows by differentiation of this expression and noting that the $n$th derivative can be written as
\begin{equation}
D^n[M(t)]=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{i}D^{n-i}[K(t)]D^i[M(t)]
\end{equation}
Where $D^k$ denotes the $k$th derivative. Now setting $t=0$:
\begin{equation}
\theta_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{i}\kappa_{n-i}\theta_i\\
\theta_n=\kappa_n+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{i}\kappa_{n-i}\theta_i\\
\end{equation}
Rewriting yields:
\begin{equation}
\kappa_n = \theta_n-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{i}\kappa_{n-i}\theta_i
\end{equation}
In terms of the central moments and cumulants.

Answer (score 3):

The paper mentioned and the formula cited by Itronneberg still refer to "raw" (non-central, "at the origin") moments. To verify this, take n=3: you get $\kappa_3 = \theta_3 - \kappa_1\theta_2$. *(EDIT: fixed according to comment by Gâteau-Gallois)* Hence, $\theta_n$ clearly denotes raw moments: the cumulant and the central moment should coincide for $n=3$.

Indeed, the [paper quoted](http://doi.org/10.1080/00031305.1995.10476146) doesn't have any reference to central moments.

Another paper, however (which also mentions the former paper), does: [Relationships Between Central Moments and Cumulants, with Formulae for the Central Moments of Gamma Distributions](https://doi.org/10.1081/STA-120018823). And it provides the following formula (eq. (2.2)):

$$
\kappa_r = \mu_r - \sum_{j=1}^{r-2} {r-1 \choose j} \mu_j \kappa_{r-j} \qquad r \geq 2.
$$

Indeed, if you set $r=2$, you get that the summation is empty, and $\kappa_2 = \mu_2$.

Comment: It's true, yet it's false. 
If $\theta_1$ was indeed the first central moment, you would have $\theta_1 = 0$ and the formule $\kappa_2 = \theta_2$ makes total sense. However, you are right in the sense that the formula above is not true, and is indeed the one for raw moments: take $n = 3$ and you end up with $\kappa_3 = \theta_3 - \kappa_1 \theta_2$. This last term on the R.H.S. is not zero, yet it should be. 
Thanks a lot for finding this second formula ! This one appears correct: for $r = 3$ I have $\kappa_3 = \mu_3 - 2 \mu_1 \kappa_2$ and since $\mu_1 = 0$ this makes sense. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @Gâteau-Gallois, fixed the counterargument!